# JS: Remove Element from an Array based on RegExp

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a JavaScript array going somewhat like

- screw cap bottle [tech.]
- nonreturnable bottle  magnum  empty
- tank
- diving  magnetic bottle [tech.]
- unbreakable bottle
- full
- tank
- diving
- **Stuff (5 of 5)**
- eine Flasche austrinken  ein Baby mit
- der Flasche ernÃ¤hren  ein Baby mit
- der Flasche fÃ¼ttern  mit der Flasche
- aufziehen

My problem is the element "*Stuff (5 of 5)*". Basically, I dont want this to appear in the array. It wouldnt be a big problem if the was always the same, but the array is generated dynamically and the numbers behind **differ**. So, for example, on time it is *"Stuff (2 of 3)"*, another time *"Stuff (6 of 6)"* and so on and so on. The first part stays the same.

So I thought Regular Expressions would solve the problem as thats what they actually are for.
So I hacked together this code:

```
var regExpStuff = /Stuff\b/;
var array = removeItem(unique, regExpStuff);
```

The function *removeItem()* looks like this:

```
//remove item (string or number) from an array
    function removeItem(originalArray, itemToRemove) {
        var j = 0;
        while (j < originalArray.length) {
            if (originalArray[j] == itemToRemove) {
                originalArray.splice(j, 1);
        } else { j++; }
    }
    return originalArray;
    }
```

The function works fine with simple strings like "string", but it doesn't this way.
Any ideas what could be wrong? Help is highly appreciated,

Benny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `if (originalArray[j] == itemToRemove)`, you are checking whether `originalArray[j]` is *equal to* the parameter.  Since the string `"# Stuff (5 of 5)"` is not *equal* to your regex (after all, it's a string, not a regex), you're not removing anything.

You need to change the method to check the regex.
For example:

```
function removeMatching(originalArray, regex) {
    var j = 0;
    while (j < originalArray.length) {
        if (regex.test(originalArray[j]))
            originalArray.splice(j, 1);
        else
            j++;
    }
    return originalArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a graphical solution to the remove of the elements
i like to see how things are changing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var fruits= ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
    for (var i=0;i<fruits.length;i++){

    if( fruits[i] == "Lemon" ){ //remove Lemon
      var citrus = fruits.splice(i,1);
      i--;
    }
    if( fruits[i] == "Apple" ){ //remove Apple
      var citrus = fruits.splice(i,1);
      i--;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits+'<br>'+citrus;
 }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```